# tensoflow slim inception v1 implementation don't have auxiliary classifiers

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I recently start to read this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.4842v1) about inception v1. in section 5, they show me a picture of the architecture of this network. I notice there are 2 auxiliary classifier to boost the back prop signal.

[image]

but these 2 auxiliary node are not implemented by tensorflow slim inception v1, code is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/nets/inception_v1.py):

I am a engineer, but I don't have many experience of reading papers, can someone help me understand this,?